# How to require different packages on Heroku to local box?

Tags: python, heroku, pip, requirements.txt

I'm writing a Python Flask app to [deploy on Heroku](http://blog.y3xz.com/blog/2012/08/16/flask-and-postgresql-on-heroku/). It will use a database. For local development, I'd like to use Sqlite, but when deployed to Heroku I'd like to use Postgresql. How can I achieve this?

I'm stuck because I don't know how to require a different set of packages between my box and the Heroku server.

---

Were this a Ruby app I would write in my `Gemfile`

```
gem "pg", :group => :production
gem "sqlite3", :group => :development
```

Then Bundler would install the appropriate packages in development and in production. But I don't know any analogous workflow for [Python's pip](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip)

Comment: The bounty was meant for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13868503/how-to-freeze-requirements-that-cant-be-satisfied-locally

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, you have two things to solve.

First, the `requirements.txt` which isn't that much of a problem. You can either throw all the requirements in the same `requirements.txt` file, having both database bindings installed doesn't harm anything. If you want to separate, however, just use `requirements.txt` for deploying, and `requirements-dev.txt` for local development.

More important is the DB settings itself, and for that you have a one liner solution:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ.get(
    'DATABASE_URL', 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db')
```

Since `DATABASE_URL` is set on Heroku, but not on local (make sure this is the case), `os.environ.get` will not find it, thus reverting to the default, which is the sqlite connection string .

Comment: I am in the same situation,except I want to run Postgres locally. What is the Postgres connection string? Thanks.

Comment: `postgres://localhost/dbname`?

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out - I just had installed Postgres improperly for some reason - so I had to reinstall to get it to work.