# How to freeze requirements that can't be satisfied locally?

Tags: python, heroku, pip

I'm writing a Python app to deploy on Heroku. Per [Heroku's guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python), I need to list package  requirements in a Pip `requirements.txt` file. The guide instructs me to install the packages locally, then run `pip freeze > requirements.txt` to write the frozen requirements file.

*However*, one of the packages I want to use in deployment on Heroku **can't be installed locally**. It's incompatible with my operating system.

So how do I write a `requirements.txt` including this package suitable for Heroku?

The only way I can think of is to write it by hand - but this would be tedious, because the **package in question has many dependencies of its own**. Besides, this defeats the point of the package manager.

---

When deploying Ruby apps to Heroku, Bundler makes this easy. In my Gemfile I write

```
gem "pg", :group => :production
gem "sqlite3", :group => :development
```

The command `bundle install` then writes a frozen version list `Gemfile.lock` (analogous to `requirements.txt`). It doesn't *install* the packages listed under the 'production' group, but it still freezes a consistent list of versioned packages.

Example: [Gemfile](https://github.com/matt-hickford/placeboxy/blob/master/Gemfile) and [Gemfile.lock](https://github.com/matt-hickford/placeboxy/blob/master/Gemfile.lock)

Comment: I don't think it would be too hard (and it would make a lot of sense in the long run) to get an Ubuntu or Debian VBox image running & install all the packages you want under a virtual env then generate your requirements.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. Issue reported to pip https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/747

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than one file, and call them different things, but Heroku does expect a requirements.txt.  For instance, for dev, you could maintain a dev_requirements.txt

Locally you can run:

```
$ pip freeze > dev_requirements.txt
```

etc, and

```
$ pip install -r dev_requirements.txt
```

and Heroku will run:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Hi Neil. My question is, how do I write `requirements.txt` for Heroku?

Comment: pip freeze > requirements.txt, then edit the appropriate part that's wrong?